# Set downloading windows position

Tags: javascript, jsp, download

When we click on a link, some links may prompt us to select open with or save options. Can we set the position of this popup in javascript or jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible with pure javascript/jsp. javascript can affect to elements in document, not browser settings or dialogs. And also jsp can affect to content from http server, not client side, of course browser things.